# React - I am passing state from a child to a parent component but the state value is off by one update cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently using the the following code to pass a state value to a parent component. However, the input text if off by one character. I know that it is due to the fact that I am changing state and passing it in the same function but how would I fix this? I can't seem to get my head around it.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.parentmethod = this.parentmethod.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      datafromChild: ''
    };
  }
  //here 'data' represents the data recieved from the child when this method gets called inside the child
  parentmethod(data) {
    this.setState({
      datafromChild: data
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child methodfromparent={this.parentmethod} /> 
        <br/><br/>
        <hr/><strong>Inside Parent</strong>
        <h5>Data from Child:<br />{this.state.datafromChild}
        <hr/>
        </h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data: ''
    };
  }
  
 
  
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      data: event.target.value
    });
    this.props.methodfromparent(this.state.data);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     <hr/><strong>Inside Child</strong>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         <hr/>
       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child component change

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      data: event.target.value
    });
    this.props.methodfromparent(this.state.data);
}
```

to this

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      data: event.target.value
    });
    this.props.methodfromparent(event.target.value);
}
```

setState is asynchronous. So when you run the parent method it is not receiving the most up to date value, it's receiving the value from the previous render. Rather than sending the parent the state, just send it the same value that you're setting in your child.

Answer (score 1):

SetState is indeed asynchronous and both your requests will not fire at the same time. To make sure that `this.props.methodfromparent(this.state.data)` is using the updated value of `this.state.data`, you can use the setState callback to make sure your first request is complete before actioning the second one as below:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      data: event.target.value
    },
    () => this.props.methodfromparent(this.state.data) // the callback here
    );
}
```